# What is the max number of indexes lucene.net can handle in a document

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

Lucene does not document the limitations of the storage engine. Does anyone know the max number of indexes allowed per document?

Comment: What do you mean by "max number of indexes"? An index is composed of documents which are composed of fields which are composed of terms. Do you mean max number of fields?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Do you know the max number of fields that can be indexed in a document?

Answer (score 2):

When referring to term numbers, Lucene's current implementation uses a Java int to hold the term index, which means the maximum number of unique terms in any single index segment is ~2.1 billion times the term index interval (default 128) = ~274 billion. This is technically not a limitation of the index file format, just of Lucene's current implementation.

Similarly, Lucene uses a Java int to refer to document numbers, and the index file format uses an Int32 on-disk to store document numbers. This is a limitation of both the index file format and the current implementation. Eventually these should be replaced with either UInt64 values, or better yet, VInt values which have no limit.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html#Limitations

Answer (score 1):

As is suggested for all types of indexes (Lucene, RDBMS, or otherwise), the lowest possible number of fields is suggested to be indexed because it keeps your index size small and reduces run-time overhead reading from the index.

That said, the field count limitations are limited by your system resources. Fields are identified by their name (case-sensitive) rather than by an arbitrary numeric ID which typically becomes the limiting factor in these sorts of systems. Theoretical field count limitations are also hard to predict in a system without strict maximum field name lengths like Lucene.

I've personally used more than 200 analyzed fields more than 2 billion documents without issue. At the same time, performance for the same index was not what I have come to expect with smaller indexes on a medium-sized Azure VM.